# Classifying the critical points of a multivariable function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Given the function: $f(x,y)=\frac32x-\frac12x^3-xy^2$

Thanks to the gradient I managed to find that the critical points are:

$(1,0),\ (-1,0),\ (0,-\sqrt{\frac32}),\ (0,+\sqrt\frac32)$

Then I found the Hessian matrix and calculated the discriminant.
The problem is, when I try to find the "A" component of the discriminant (disc= AC-$B^2$)
I get $0$ for the points (0,-$\sqrt\frac32$),(0,+$\sqrt\frac32$).
although the discriminant itself is $>0$.

So what are these points
(0,-$\sqrt\frac32$),(0,+$\sqrt\frac32$) and how can I classify them?

Comment: $$(1;0)$$ is a maximum point and $$(-1;0)$$ a minimium point

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner what about the two other points that I mentioned?

Comment: There's no "4" the formula for the discriminant.

Comment: @B.Goddard fixed that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $q_\pm=(\pm 1,0)$, ${\rm det\ Hess}\ f>0$ : Hence it is local
minimum or local maximum : $f(1,0)=1$ and $f(1+\epsilon,0)=1
  - \frac{3}{2}\epsilon^2  - \frac{1}{2}\epsilon^3$ so that $q_+$ is local maximum

Since $f(-1,0)=-1$ and $f(-1-\epsilon,0)=-f(1+\epsilon,0)$ so it is
local minimum

For $p_\pm
 = (0,\pm\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}})$, $ {\rm
det\ Hess}\ f <0$ Hence at $p_+$, there are two curves $\alpha_i$
s.t. $f\circ \alpha_1$ has local minimum and $f\circ \alpha_2$ has
local maximum

Comment: opss, I substituted x,y the opposite way in the det of the hessian so I got det Hess f >0 in the last two points, so They are saddle points, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Fot $t \in \mathbb R$ let $g(t):=f(t, \pm \sqrt{\frac{3}{2}})= -\frac{1}{2}t^3.$

Then $g(0)=0, g(t)<0$, if $t>0$ and $g(t)>0$, if $t<0$.

This shows that $f$ has not a local minimum or maximum in the points $(0, \pm \sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}).$

Comment: thank you, but why the gradient is zero in this points? they are critical points, but not maximum or minimum and even not a saddle?